# Removing some text string and characters from a column in dataframe in R

Tags: r, gsub

I acknowledge this has been asked in different ways in the past. However, I get lost with `gsub`.

I have this dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(Real = c(7.76, 5.55, 4.8, 4.68, 7.43, 4.59), Predicted = c(7.36, 
5.28, 5.12, 4.47, 7.48, 4.69), PdivR = c(0.95, 0.95, 1.07, 0.96, 
1.01, 1.02), Regression = c("`TLC`~`7_A`.152534", "`TLC`~`7_A`.158324", 
"`TLC`~`7_A`.611461", "`TLC`~`7_A`.627267", "`TLC`~`7_A`.674564", 
"`TLC`~`7_A`.675169")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which can be displayed in this way:

```
head(df)
  Real Predicted PdivR         Regression
1 7.76      7.36  0.95 `TLC`~`7_A`.152534
2 5.55      5.28  0.95 `TLC`~`7_A`.158324
3 4.80      5.12  1.07 `TLC`~`7_A`.611461
4 4.68      4.47  0.96 `TLC`~`7_A`.627267
5 7.43      7.48  1.01 `TLC`~`7_A`.674564
6 4.59      4.69  1.02 `TLC`~`7_A`.675169
```

I would like to remove in the column `Regression` the point `.` and the numbers to the right of the point, and also this symbol (upper comma) in order to keep only `TLC ~ 7_A`.

Be aware that the number of numbers to the right are diverse along the column, but the behaviour is the same.

How could I do it with `gsub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can match the `.`(`\\.` - escaped as it is a metacharacter that matches any character) and one or more digits (`\\d+`) till the end (`$`) of the string and replace with blank (`""`) and wrap with `gsub` to match the backquote ("`") and remove it

```
df$Regression <- gsub("`", "", sub("\\.\\d+$", '', df$Regression))
df$Regression
[1] "TLC~7_A" "TLC~7_A" "TLC~7_A" "TLC~7_A" "TLC~7_A" "TLC~7_A"
```

Comment: Great. And what about removing the "upper comma"? @akrun

Comment: @antecessor you meant backquotes

Comment: yes, I didn't know how to name in English, sorry...

Comment: @antecessor updated the post. .  Just wrap with `gsub`

Comment: Great! Everything perfect!